# tree dict in python with integer keys

Tags: python, tree

I need tree dict, that support integer keys

```
d = TreeDict()
d[6] = 5
d[4] = 3
```

etc

or i need solution, to store integer keys in this nice lib: http://www.stat.washington.edu/~hoytak/code/treedict/api.html

Comment: I am sorry but your question is not really clear. You want an implementation of a tree dictionary? You can just make a hash table which has buckets as binary trees.

Comment: How is this different from the standard `dict` class?  Keys can be integers in a `dict`.

Comment: i need tree dict for it's sort property, so standard hash dict - not my case

Comment: You can use the library you mention with keys of the form `'x%d' % number`.  It's a hack but maybe good enough for your use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, i forgot word "binary", when google it

```
pip install binarytrees
```